How to evaluate whether the results of multiple games conform to the probability distribution of their respective states
There are $n$ games, and each game has a state after the start.
Based on this state, the probability of the outcome of the game can be calculated.
For example, there are 3 type of results, and the probabilities are $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ respectively.
But in the next game, the game state is different, and the probabilities change accordingly, becoming $p_4$, $p_5$, and $p_6$.
Play $n$ games, and then there are $n$ results.
So how to judge whether these $n$ results are in line with these probabilities as a whole?
I have no idea. Maybe I can use the chi-square test, but the conditions don't seem to be met?

In your data, do you observe the game-state (after start) and the outcome for each data point?

Using surprisal as a test statistic, we can use Monte Carlo simulation to test if the observed results are consistent with the hypothesized probabilities ($p_i$).
Demonstrating in R:
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 316938477
set.seed(seed)
m <- 3L # number of outcomes per game
n <- 100L # number of games

# generate the "true" probabilities for each game
collapse::setop(p <- matrix(rexp(m*n), m, n), "/", colSums(p), rowwise = TRUE)

Each column of p contains the probabilities of observing outcome 1, 2, or 3. Now, simulate a single set of results that will represent the "observed" outcome using those probabilities.
pp <- cumsum(p)
x0 <- findInterval(0:(n - 1) + runif(n), pp)%%m + 1L

x0 contains one outcome for each of the n = 100 games. Next, calculate the surprisal of our 100 observed outcomes.
# calculate the surprisal of the results
(s0 <- -sum(log(p[cbind(x0, 1:n)])))
#> [1] 84.40602

This will serve as the test statistic, which is a random variate from an underlying distribution. Use Monte Carlo simulation to estimate the distribution of the test statistic for our hypothesized probabilities (p).
# Monte Carlo simulation of surprisal from 1M replications
# (1M is probably way more than needed, but it only takes a few seconds).
N <- 1e6
x <- findInterval(0:(n - 1) + runif(n*N), pp)%%m + 1L
s <- -colSums(matrix(log(p[cbind(x, 1:n)]), n, N))

Summarize the distribution (also try hist(s, 100)).
summary(s)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   65.25   82.10   85.56   85.79   89.24  118.23

Now, estimate the quantile of the surprisal of the observed results from the hypothetical distribution.
mean(s0 > s)
#> [1] 0.412846

This is in the high-density region of the distribution, so we may conclude that the observed outcomes are consistent with the hypothesized probabilities.
Compare these results to those from a set of observations that come from a different process (i.e., not according to p).
x1 <- sample(m, n, 1)
(s1 <- -sum(log(p[cbind(x1, 1:n)])))
#> [1] 157.0932
mean(s1 > s)
#> [1] 1

The observed surprisal is in the far tail of the approximate distribution, meaning the observed outcomes are highly unlikely to have been generated by the hypothesized process (p).
